# How to replace certain content of a line in file by using bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file

```
versions:
  - sha: 123456789
```

and now I want to replace the `123456789`. Could anybody tell me what I should do to achieve this goal by using bash? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is this a yaml file? And replace with what?

Comment: do you mean, using only the bash interpreter or you can use typical programs like sed from inside the script ? if it so, you can do sed -i 's/old-text/new-text/g' input.txt

Comment: @Shawn Yes it is. I just want to replace with a variable (that I would read from git log)

Comment: @PabloYaggi Yep I can use sed, but I'm wondering how can I do with indexing? For example in java we can do something like `s.substring(0, 5)`. Because I may not know the number after `sha:` exactly, the `123456789` is just an example.

Comment: use sed with a regular expression that detects the sha you want to replace, can't post a specific answer cause the question is closed.

Comment: I strongly suggest using a tool like [yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) that understands the YAML format instead of trying to use regular expressions/sed.